# Chrome extension - how to get response of POST request user invoked from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that navigates to a webpage, lets the user click a button on the webpage that sends an asynchronous post request, and to read that response and use it in the extension.

Everything that I am finding from my research is telling me to create the request in the extension itself, which I do not want to do, because I need the web page to make the request itself.

Is there a way to listen to a post request on the page itself on my background script?

Comment: So the website uses AJAX?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and [`onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) to fire when a request is about to occur `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function callback)`. Parameters contains the HTTP request data. You also need to supply an extraInfoSpec of `requestBody` to the listener.

Below is a sample code snippet how to use onBeforeRequest:

```
const WEB_REQUEST = chrome.webRequest;

WEB_REQUEST.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {
if(details.method == "POST")
console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
},
);
```

For more information regarding POST request, try to read the Chrome Extensions developer guide: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted